# Bootstrap for Solidus frontend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, solidus

I am using Solidus for the first time. I have been able to have it working as required. However, I am trying to make changes to the frontend. Although I'd rather use bootstrap 4, I could only find a way to port it with bootstrap 3 using a gem as described [here](https://github.com/2beDigital/solidus_bootstraps_frontend).

I have followed the instruction as explained on the page. However when I make the test changes described, expecting to see the same changes, nothing happens. In fact the page is no longer structured as it was initially which I suppose is due to overwriting all.css used by spree on the app.

I am not sure why things are not working. I tried to undo changes by running `rails destroy solidus_bootstrap_frontend:install` but this doesn't restore the changes. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

run

```
rails solidus_bootstrap_frontend:install
```

It'll tell you what files it tries to create, and will probably ask if you want to overwrite them.

Delete these files and you'll reset the appearance to how it was before you ran the command

Comment: Sorry for my late response. Did you mean `rails g solidus_bootstrap_frontend:install`? Because the one you provided caused error and the one with `generate` only regenerates the files. I deleted the ones created and got errors. I also deleted the ones meant to be overwritten and got errors